How can I use NLog with Elasticsearch 8.15.3
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true">

    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
        <add assembly="NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch"/>
    </extensions>


    <targets async="true">

        <target name="elastic" xsi:type="ElasticSearch" index=" MyServiceName-${date:format=yyyy.MM.dd}"
                uri="http://localhost:9200"
                layout ="API:MyServiceName|${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" >
        </target>

    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="elastic" />
    </rules>
</nlog>

I'm trying to get working the NLog with target to Elasticsearch in my ASP.NET Core 8 Web API application.
I'm using Elasticsearch, Nest and Elasticsearch.NET v8.15.3.
The logs are not getting save in Elasticsearch please help me if anyone know about how to use NLog with Elasticsearch latest version.

When troubleshooting NLog then it is recommended to enable throwConfigExceptions="true" and check the NLog InternalLogger for warnings / errors. Maybe Elastic-Search is expecting https but you are using http ? Think you have to specify documentType="" when connecting to Elastic ver. 8. Maybe consider changing to the official Elastic.NLog.Targets
